# Detecting image inversion

Tags: matlab, image-processing

So suppose I have a 16-bit intensity image in Matlab and would like to determine whether the signal is black and the background is white, or if the signal is white and the background is black. What is a computationally efficient way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I think that this is computationally equivalent to the *zebra-decision problem* which, to paraphrase, is *Is a zebra white with black stripes or black with white stripes ?*.  This is known, by me, to be NP-complete.

Comment: Ok, I never realized that such a problem would be NP-complete. Thank you.

Comment: If you have more info about your signal, you can avoid NP completeness.  If you know for instance that 75% of the pixels are background, and 25% are foreground it's easy to determine.  You just have to be more explicit in the problem description.

Comment: If you make an assumption that image is somewhat sparse, just count the number of black or white pixels, whichever occurs more you can consider to be your background color. But as previously stated, it is highly dependent on your problem description